# Criar estruturas dinâmicas baseadas de um ficheiro de texto

Tags: c, arquivo, lista

É possível criar uma estrutura dinâmica com base em informação armazenada num ficheiro(arquivo) de texto? Ou isso só é possível se o ficheiro for binário?

Por exemplo: se eu tiver um numero (5) num ficheiro de texto, eu posso ir busca-lo e guarda-lo numa estrutura dinâmica como inteiro? Ou isso é impossível porque o os dados dos ficheiros de textos são todos 'char'?

Comment: Os ficheiros de texto podem-se comportar como se fossem teclado. Também os dados do teclado são todos `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possivel. Você le o char do arquivo para memoria e depois faz o cast normalmente. O arquivo é basicamente outro tipo de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Os caracteres dos arquivos são os mesmos da tabela *Ascii*, ou seja, é um `char` com o valor de **0** a **255**, assim como os valores permitidos para um `char` em **C**.

Caso queira pegar um numero de um arquivo, claro que ficaria mais fácil se o valor do arquivo estivesse em binário. Pois no arquivo teria um valor de **4** espaços com valores de **0** a **255**, responsáveis por armazenar um inteiro.

**E se for um número representado pelos caracteres 43?**

Para isso deve se lembrar que esses caracteres são representados por valores binários da tabela *Ascii*. Se fosse ler o arquivo e pegar esses valores, teria os valores **52** e **51**, pois são os valores que representam os caracteres **4** e **3**.

**Como passar isso para uma variável inteira?**

É necessário q se saiba o tamanho do valore a ser lido. Supondo que o arquivo possua o valor **4378**, lemos o arquivo e armazenamos o valor em um `char num[4]`, devemos percorrer o `char` de frente para trás para o calculo.

```
int number = 0; // deve-se iniciar o valor em 0
for(int x = 0; x<4; x++){
    number += pow(10,x)*num[3-x]; // a posição é sempre o tamanho do vetor - 1
}

printf("%d\n", number);
```

```
4378
```